# Count the number of clusters on a UMAP scatterplot (without providing labels)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, seurat

I have a dataframe with columns 'x' and 'y' corresponding to x/y coordinates of a scatterplot I've made using ggplot2. I'm looking for some way to ask, "how many clusters exist here?". I understand that maybe some user input may be required here for what you want to call a 'cluster'.

I have found some success using Seurat, because it contains a function to label clusters. However, it's more like finding the clusters that correspond to a vector of labels provided by the user (ex: I proivde 5 unique labels so just go find 5 clusters).

**Min Reprex:**

Seurat's `LabelClusters` function is very useful for labeling clusters starting solely from X/Y coordinates:

```
library(umap)
library(Seurat)
my_umap <- umap(iris[,c(1:4)])
my_umap <- as.data.frame(my_umap$layout)
my_umap$id <- iris$Species
colnames(my_umap) <- c("x","y", "id")

p <- ggplot(my_umap, aes(x=x,y=y,color=id)) + geom_point()

LabelClusters(plot=p, id='id', color="black")
```

[Image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcuPh.png)

However, I have a need to detect total # of clusters from these data (without providing labels). By this I mean first detecting how many clusters exist . Maybe here we would see 5 clusters instead of 3 :

[And here is that result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJEQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the number of clusters is very subjective. Different algorithms give different results and it is up to the data analyst to decide what is an appropriate clustering. There are some clusterings that are better than others, but what algorithm is optimal for calling clusters is dependent on the data. For example, if you generate random noise, clustering algorithms most likely *will* find clusters, but because the data is noise, these are meaningless.

I'm going to caution against calling clusters in UMAP space. UMAP is an nearest neighbour embedding method that is constrained to 2/3 dimensions. This constraint loses a lot of potentially useful information. I think a generally useful strategy is to compute a (shared) nearest neighbour graph on the data (or a number of principal components), through for example `bluster::makeSNNGraph()` and then use `igraph::cluster_louvain()`, or some other method, to call clusters.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(umap)

data <- as.matrix(iris[, 1:4])

my_umap <- as.data.frame(umap(data)$layout)

graph <- bluster::makeSNNGraph(data)
#> Warning in (function (to_check, X, clust_centers, clust_info, dtype, nn, :
#> detected tied distances to neighbors, see ?'BiocNeighbors-ties'
clust <- igraph::cluster_louvain(graph)

my_umap$clust <- factor(clust$membership)

ggplot(my_umap, aes(V1, V2, colour = clust)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>